# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: json, http, post, dart, flutter

I am trying to post a nested JSON object to an API. Here is the simple code that I am trying.

```
Map m = {
   "email": 's@a.com',
   "password": "123",
   "billing" : {
      "first_name": "Samarth",
      "last_name": "Agarwal",
   }
};

final response = await http.post(url, body: m, headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Accept": "application/json"
});
```

I get the error message: 
`type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`. If I do not pass in the `billing` object, which is another map in itself, then the request completes successfully.

How can I successfully send a nested JSON object to an API using HTTP in dart?

Answer (score 0):

You need to json encode it with `json.encode(m)` and then send that as the body.

Comment: That will convert json to a string avd the api doesn't accept string. I have tried that.